# Extract only records that meet ALL criteria in R: code worked as expected on sample data but not on real data

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to extract records (e.g. site_code) that meet ALL specified criteria (e.g. 4 specified years) from a dataset that contains a bunch of site codes and year. I first created a sample code with simplified sample data to verify the code/logic, and it worked as expected (`reprex_1`). However when I apply this approach to my real data (`reprex_2` in which I want to extract only those site_code/s that cover all four seasons (2019, 2020, 2021, 2022); I don't want any site_code/s that cover only part of the four seasons) the code actually returns all site_codes rather than the record that meet the criteria.

As far as I can see the two codes have identical data structure. During my investigation I also noticed that in `reprex_2` if I reduce the length of `season_criteria` to 1 (for example, 2019 only) the filtration worked properly (extracted only those site_codes that occurred only in 2019), whereas it just doesn't work as expected when the length is put back to 4. It seems somehow either `all()` or `%in%` is not working as expected here, but why?? Am I missing something here?

My R, RStudio and all packages (on MS Win10) are updated to the latest as of this writing (Thu 28/July/2022).

```
library(dplyr)

# REPREX_1: this works as expected ----------------------------

criteria <- c(2, 3, 4)

df4replex_1 <- data.frame(
  Group = LETTERS[c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3)],   # Group A, B, C
  Value = c(1:2, 2:4, 2:5))                # only Group_B meets requirement

df4replex_1 %>% 
  table()

df4replex_1 %>% 
  group_by(Group) %>% 
  filter(all(Value %in% criteria)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  table()
# works as expected; only Group_B is extracted.


# REPREX_2: somehow this doesn't work as expected despite same logic/structure as reprex_1------------

season_criteria <- 2019:2022

df4reprex_2 <- data.frame(
  site_code = c(rep("4-001-01", 9),   # 2019 x 2, 2020 x 7
                rep("4-005-01", 1),   # 2019 x 1
                rep("4-060-21", 6),   # 2019 x 4, 2020 x 2
                rep("4-060-22", 6),   # 2019 x 4, 2020 x 2
                rep("4-096-01", 11),  # 2019 x 2, 2020 x 3, 2021 x 3, 2022 x 3
                rep("4-096-04", 2)),  # 2022 x 2
  season = c(rep(2019, 2), rep(2020, 7),                                 # 4-001-01
             rep(2019, 1),                                               # 4-005-01
             rep(2019, 4), rep(2020, 2),                                 # 4-060-21
             rep(2019, 4), rep(2020, 2),                                 # 4-060-22
             rep(2019, 2), rep(2020, 3), rep(2021, 3), rep(2022, 3),     # 4-096-01; meet requirement
             rep(2022, 2))                                               # 4-096-04
)

   
df4reprex_2 %>% 
  group_by(site_code) %>% 
  filter(all(season %in% season_criteria)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  table()
# somehow doesn't work properly; should have extracted site_code "4-096-01" only rather than returning all site_codes.
```

Answer (score 1):

To filter for sites which contain all `season_criteria` use `all(season_criteria %in% season)`. The other way around you only check that `seasons`s are included in `season_criteria` which is obviously true for all sites:

```r
library(dplyr)

df4reprex_2 %>% 
  group_by(site_code) %>% 
  filter(all(season_criteria %in% season)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  table()
#>           season
#> site_code  2019 2020 2021 2022
#>   4-096-01    2    3    3    3
```